# Django model method not making changes to object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a method on my model to change an object from being published to unpublished. The redirect works alright but in my database, nothing happens. If the object is published it remains so with no changes to it when the button is clicked to unpublish the object(blog post article)

**This is the model and the method**

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)

   def unpublish(self):
        self.published == False
        self.save()
```

My view

```py
def unpublish_post(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    post.unpublish
    return redirect('dashboard')
```

**Edit 2: My view**

```py
@require_http_methods(['POST', 'DELETE'])
def unpublish_post(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if post.published == True:
        post.unpublish()
        return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        return messages.warning(request, "Post already not published")
    return redirect('dashboard')
```

**My urls.py**

```py
    path('unpublish-post/<slug>/', unpublish_post, name='unpublish-post'),
```

**EDIT 1**: Now I updated the view logic with:

```
def unpublish_post(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if post.published == True:
        post.unpublish()
        return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        return messages.warning(request, "Post already not published")
```

Comment: `self.published = False` (with one `=`), not `self.published == False`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Still nothing happens. I changed it

Comment: you need to *call* `unpublish`, so `post.unpublish()`.

Comment: Thank you @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Please do not "vandalize" your post. Simply add EDITs at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Thank you @WillemVanOnsem Sorry about that. I was trying to refactor it

Answer (score 0):

There are three minor mistakes:

1. you set a variable with a single equal sign (`=`), not a double equal sign (`==`);
2. you should *call* the `.unpublish()` method; and
3. you should only allow to access this view in a POST or DELETE request.

In your model, we thus rewrite the logic to:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # …

    def unpublish(self):
        self.published = False
        self.save()
```

and in the view, we call the method and restrict access to a POST and/or a DELETE request:

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@require_http_methods(['POST', 'DELETE'])
def unpublish_post(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    post.unpublish()
    return redirect('dashboard')
```

The client thus then will need to make a POST/DELETE request, not a GET request. The template thus should look like:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% 'unpublish-post' post.slug %}">
    <input type="submit" value="unpublish">
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome @Willem
I am yet to implement your code. However, I've updated the view. It throws an error "The view blog.views.unpublish_post didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead" if the post is unpublished and I try to republish it again

Comment: @samhassan: you need to `return` a HTTP response, for example `return redirect('dashboard')` as you wrote yourself.

Comment: @samhassan: in your updated view, you do this only if the `post` is not yet deleted. You should also return something in the `else` case.

Comment: I have put "return None" in the else statement. This is the error thrown "Method Not Allowed (GET): /unpublish-post/django-tutorials/
[18/Aug/2021 19:07:36] "GET /unpublish-post/django-tutorials/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0"
Th page isn't working is also thrown  on the webpage

Comment: Can you please take a look at the changes made pleae

Comment: @samhassan: you need to work with a POST request as is specified in the answer, so you remove a `Post` object with a "mini-form", for example `<form method="POST" action="url-to-remove-post"><input type="submit" value="remove"></form>`, and then you press the button of that mini-form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236156/discussion-between-sam-hassan-and-willem-van-onsem).